# Five new results on Conway's 99-graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, open-problem

I realize that this editing won't make the question open (since this is against the guidelines to share results and ask to check them). Meanwhile, I'd like to replace a lot of text with a [link](https://figshare.com/articles/preprint/Five_New_Results_on_Conway_s_99-Graph_Problem/23732622) so those who can see it won't have problems with rendering.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147716/discussion-on-question-by-bertrand-haskell-five-new-results-on-conways-99-graph); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.